# Widget and MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

this is my code:

```
mLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
mChart = new OpenChart(this);
setCentralWidget(mChart);
mLayout->addWidget(mChart);
mLayout->setMargin(0);
setLayout(mLayout);
QMap<QString,double> empleados;
empleados["Ana"]=5000.0;
empleados["Juan"]=6000.0;
empleados["Luis"]=7000.0;
empleados["Jorge"]=8000.0;
empleados["Francisco"]=100.0;
empleados["Mario"]=10000.0;
mChart->setTitle("sueldos");
mChart->setTipo(OpenChart::Sectores_2D);
mChart->setTipoleyenda(OpenChart::Circular);
const auto empleadosEnd=empleados.end();
for(auto i=empleados.begin();i!=empleadosEnd;++i)
{mChart->addItem(i.key(),i.value());}
```

Output:
[image]

I want the widget to display on the whole window of mainwindow  !! Help me Please !!!!!

Comment: first create the `mChart` object without a parent, set all its parameters, add data, then create the `mLayout` object, add `mChart` to it, then set it as the layout for the mainWindow.

Comment: or just use `QChartView` you don't need `QVBoxLayot` with it. read documentation.

Comment: You appear to be calling `setLayout` on a `QMainWindow`?  You shouldn't do that.  You are probably getting error messages along the lines of ``setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout " on QMainWindow ", which already has a layout''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a `QWidget` with parent as your mainwindow.
- Add chart widget to your vboxlayout.
- Set the vBoxLayout to dummy widget created in first step.
- Then assign dummy widget as central widget.

**rough code below:**

```
mLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

QWidget *vBox = new QWidget(this);

mChart = new OpenChart(this);

mLayout->addWidget(mChart);

vBox->setLayout(mLayout);

setCentralWidget(vBox);
```

Do not call `setLayout` again, as the layout is already set to a `QWidget` (vbox).